# Vector<std::pair> initializing index 0 with incorrect values c++

Tags: c++, csv, vector, stl, std-pair

I have a program where I take a csv file and split up the strings and store them into a `vector<std::pair<string, float>>`

The overall program is to use the dijkstra algorithm, but thats not the issue right now.

I created my own print statement to test that the correct values were placed into the appropriate spot. But the issue is that index 0 has nothing in first and a 0 in second and then everything else works as normal.

In my header I declare my vector like this:

```
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> curr_graph; //vector that hold a pair, string = currency name, int = bribe cost
```

My cpp file the only function being used is node_input() and my print function

```
void graph::node_input()
{
    //grabs first line of csv file (aka the nodes)
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if(s[i] == ',') amount_of_nodes++; 

    std::stringstream ss(s);
    string token;
    while(getline(ss, token, ',')) //splits up the string by commas, ex: Dollar (1.2),Peso (6) will be split up
    {
        std::stringstream sss(token);
        string split;
        int counter = 0;
        string temp;
        float bribe = 0;

        while(getline(sss, split, ' '))//splits up the newly split up string bu spaces, ex: Dollar (1.2) will be split up by the space
        {
            if(counter % 2 == 0)//this condition is when the string split is the currency
                temp = split;
            else //this condition will take to bribe cost and convert to a float
            {
                split.pop_back();//removes )
                split.erase(0,1);//removes (
                bribe = std::stof(split.c_str(), 0);//converts to float
            }
            counter++;
        }
        curr_graph.push_back(std::make_pair(temp, bribe));        
    }
    //cout << curr_graph.size();
    //cout << curr_graph.capacity();
    //cout << endl << curr_graph.front() << endl;
    print(curr_graph);
}

void graph::print(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> &v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].first << " " << v[i].second << endl;
    }
}
```

my sample input file: (compiled using <)

```
,Dollar (1.2),Peso (6),Pound (2),Euro (3),Franc (12)
Dollar (1.2),0,1.5,0,2.5,0
Peso (6),0,0,1.2,5.7,0
Pound (2),2,0,0,0,0
Euro (3),0.9,0,3,0,0
Franc (12),0,0,0,15,0
,,,,,
What is the shortest path from Pesos to Euros?,,,,,
```

and here is my output that I am getting from my print statement that is called in my node_input() function:

```
  0
 Dollar 1.2
 Peso 6
 Pound 2
 Euro 3
 Franc 12
```

Comment: How about trimming it down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I'm sure you can reproduce the same problem with much less code and probably when you try to reproduce the problem, you will figure out what's wrong yourself

Comment: Also, why wait until the very end before printing out anything?  Why not, as a debugging aid, print out the intermediate strings to make sure things are as what you believe they are?

Comment: If you stare at the "sample input", something sticks out like a very, very sore thumb. Obviously the leading comma, the very first character in the read input. Without anything coming before it. As I was going through this question, that was kind of very obvious, and very in-your-face-ish thing that just couldn't be ignored. And you're getting a strange result trying to parse comma-delimited input, also in the very first parsed value. Do you think that's a coincidence? I don't think so.

Comment: You should definitely learn to use a debugger. I'm sure it will solve your problem in seconds ;-)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Magix yes I agree, right now im using VS Code and i cant get the debugger to work on it. so I debug the old way :)

Comment: At some point you will need to learn to debug a bit.  Here's a start: https://ideone.com/YILutD